# Does it make sense that C-style matrix multiplication (3 loops) is faster than Eigen?

Tags: c++, c, eigen

Im reading some C programming textbooks to brush up, and one of the big reasons I personally enjoyed C++ over C (for my type of programs) is Eigen linear algebra.
So today I just did a simple test of a 10x10 matrix multiplication and measured the time, and surprisingly at least to me is C style has been shown to be quite faster. In release mode I am averaging <1ms for C and ~12ms for Eigen

Does it make sense that this is the case, and if yes (or no) why? I am not discrediting Eigen in any means, still my top linear algebra library and it provides a lot of other functionality. And as an avid Eigen user, is there something that can be done to improve the performance in sitatutions like the one shown below.

```
// function to multiply two matrices
void multiplyMatrices(int first[][10],
                      int second[][10],
                      int result[][10],
                      int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {

   // Multiplying first and second matrices and storing it in result
   for (int i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < c2; ++j) {
        // Init matrix
        result[i][j] = 0;
         for (int k = 0; k < c1; ++k) {
            result[i][j] += first[i][k] * second[k][j];
         }
      }
   }
}

int main() {

  int first[10][10], second[10][10], result[10][10];
  // Initializing elements to something arbitrary
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      first[i][j] = i * j;
      second[i][j] = (i + 3) * j;
    }
  }
  // multiply two matrices, only time the multiplication
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  multiplyMatrices(first, second, result, 10, 10, 10, 10);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

  std::cout << "C style: " << duration << std::endl;
  // Initialize the matrices to a fixed size
  Eigen::Matrix<int, 10, 10> f1(10, 10);
  Eigen::Matrix<int, 10, 10> f2(10, 10);
  Eigen::Matrix<int, 10, 10> r(10, 10);
  // Same initialization values as C style
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      f1(i, j) = i * j;
      f2(i, j) = (i + 3) * j;
    }
  }
  // Only time the multiplication
  t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  r = f1 * f2;
  t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

  std::cout << "Eigen: " << duration << std::endl;
```

Comment: Try putting random values into the matrixes. The way you're initializing the matrixes, the compiler may be able to calculate the result and skip all the runtime multiplication.

Comment: Have you look at asm to see if first code it not completely inlined? (so no computation at all).

Comment: @Barmar I ran it again initializing to rand() for all matrices and get similar results, C ~1ms and Eigen is slightly slower ~20ms

Comment: Eigen is only about half as fast as `multiplyMatrices`, not 12 to 20 times slower, according to some quick checks. [this test case](https://godbolt.org/z/dcGKPb), [now run 100 times](https://godbolt.org/z/qnWMr5). (these are not scientific results). Are you timing with optimisations?

Comment: there's nothing about C in this question, don't tag indiscriminately

Comment: This particular three-nested-loop gemm is really a perfect case for the compiler. It has a well-known loop access pattern, all sizes are known at compile-time, everything fits into L1. You will have a very hard time to outperform a compiler in such cases. I just tested a complete unrolling (assigning every `result[i][j]` explicitly) and the loop version is ~3x faster.

Comment: Did you try `r.noalias() = f1 * f2`? Dense matrix products can benefit from this trick.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html

Comment: Also, I tried replacing `f1` and `f2` with `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<int, 10, 10>> f1(first[0]);` to eliminate another variable. Results are very similar. Neat find!

Comment: Could be that Eigen is using Strassen matrix multiplication. This is a 'fast' asymptotically fast algorithm (O(n^2 log n) if I remember correctly) but has a larger constant K value. That means its actually slower for small matrices. Try using matrices 1000 x 1000 big and see what happens.